# Sign in with Facebook SSO in a WebView?

Tags: android, facebook, webview, single-sign-on

In my app a user signes into Facebook with SSO. 
Later on he navigates to a facebook page displayed in a WebView.
In this WebView he won't be signed in, which means the user needs to sign in to facebook twice.

Is there any way to use the "SSO sign in" to automatically sign in to a WebView?

(I have really searched everywhere but have not found any answers)

Cheers

Comment: SSO authentication does not affect the browser. Even if the user has authenticated using SSO, he / she will still have to authenticate in the browser. In this case, the `WebView` in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebView` does not share cookies/sessions with the Facebook App nor the web browser, which means that the user will unfortunately have to sign in again when hit with a Facebook URL.

However, the user is likely to have already signed into Facebook in their browser, so if you choose to instead launch the user to a Facebook page via their browser instead of a `WebView`, the chances that the user has to login again will decrease, which might be more optimal in your circumstance.